# Running model method from html anchor

Tags: php, html, laravel, anchor

How can I run model method from anchor tag ?
When I use this code :

```
<a href="{{Auth::user()->sendFriendRequest($user)}}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i></a>
```

Here's function :

```
public function sendFriendRequest(User $user)
{
    DB::table('friends_users')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('friend_id', $user->id)
    ->update(['who_send' => Auth::user()->id]);

}
```

Function runs when I enter page but not when anchor clicked.
Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not doing it correctly. PHP or Laravel Functions cannot be run through href of anchor tag.

You can do it by following way:

**In your blade or HTML file**

```
<a href="{{url('send-friend-request'.'/'.$user->id)}}" role="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-btn fa-plus"></i></a>
```

**In your Routes File i.e. web.php**

```
Route::get('send-friend-request/{user_id}', function($user_id){

    DB::table('friends_users')
    ->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)
    ->where('friend_id', $user_id)
    ->update(['who_send' => Auth::user()->id]);

    return back();  // or return redirect('any-url-here');

});
```

---

**The function which I wrote in web.php, you can also write this function in a Controller file.**

**Edit**
In above function, you can redirect user back or to any specified url. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirects

Comment: And then redirect to previous site ?

Comment: @kacper1230, yes In above function, you can redirect user back or to any specified url. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/responses#redirects. I edited my answer. Please let me know if my answer was helpful for you (by accepting it as solution :) )

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid that this is impossible, since the PHP code is generated when the HTML for that page is rendered. This causes the behaviour that you describe; the function runs when the page is loaded. If you want the code to execute upon clicking a button, then this cannot be done using a serverside language like PHP. You must use a clientside language like JavaScript for this.

Actions like these are typically implemented using the following pattern:

1. Clicking on the button triggers an AJAX request to fire, using JavaScript.
2. The AJAX request is a PHP script, which contains the code you described in your post. The result is returned mostly as JSON.
3. Your JavaScript function validates the returned JSON of step 2 and acts accordingly, for example showing a succes message.